# Enums with attributes Java

Tags: java, enums

Each color has its own static attribute - a number. I want to be able to change this value with a method. Can I do this using enums somehow? Like this or perhaps differently:

```
 public enum Color {

        RED, ORANGE, YELLOW;
}

Color.RED.setValue(x);
Color.RED.getValue();
```

Or would I have to do something like this where color is a class?

```
public Red extends Color {
   private static int x;

   public int getRedValue(){
        return x;
   }

   public void setRedValue(int x){
        this.x = x;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do the following:

```
    enum Colour{

        RED(1), BLUE(2);

        public int value;

        Colour(int valueArg){ 
            value = valueArg; 
        }

        /*public setValue(int a){
            value = a;
        }

        public getValue(){
            return value;
        }*/

    }

    public class Test{
        static Colour colour = Colour.BLUE;
        public static void main(String[] args){
            colour.value = 3;
            //colour.setValue(3);
       }
  }
```

You can do this with any variable type you'd like. 
Here, each instantiation of the `Colour` enum has an associated integer value. Optionally, make the `value` field private and create accessor and mutator methods (see the code comments). How this works is that you provide a value for the field via a constructor that you call when you make a new instantiation of the enum. You can add more fields and arguments to the constructor as you wish.

Comment: Wouldn't it be bad to allow `setValue()`? As I understand it enums are also identified via their attributes. Of course they are mainly identified by their reference, but what if you have to decide which enum to use based on the attributes? Allowing attribute changes in this case seems bad.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like -

```
public enum Color {

    RED(2), ORANGE(4), YELLOW(6);

    private int value;

    private Color (int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```